# Looping thru columns in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with structure

```
TableA
    ID   price1   price2 price3 price4 rate1 rate2 rate3 rate4
    1     10       11     12      13    2     3      2     2
```

i want to insert into another tableB

```
ID   Price Rate
 1    10    2
 1    11    3
```

Now in my cursor i am fetching all the values from TableA into variables

```
Fetch next from cursor1 into @id,@price1,@price2,@price3,@price4,@rate1,@rate2,@rate3,@rate4
```

After fetching it i want to insert into TableB

I want to loop through columns of the TableA
so the insert statement is

```
 insert into tableB (Id,Price,Rate) values (@id,@price1,@rate1)
```

But i would have to give 4 insert statement to get the values

Is there a way i can loop so i can have one single insert statement in a loop

In this example i had given just 4 columns but i have 30 columns so its essential i need to get into loop

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dont need cursors for this, it can be done straight from a query -

```
INSERT INTO TableB (id, price, rate)
select id, price1, rate1 from TableA
UNION ALL
select id, price2, rate2 from TableA
UNION ALL
select id, price3, rate3 from TableA
..
..
```

Avoid cursors if possible, they always have performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (ID, Price, Rate)
VALUES
(@id, @price1, @rate1),
(@id, @price2, @rate2),
...
```

Comment: not really... i was looking at way of replacing price1 and rate1 with rate+i and price+i something like that where i is the looping counter

Comment: @prady - If you use this syntax you can do one `INSERT` using whatever variables you have.  What you are suggesting sounds like creating a `CURSOR` using Dynamic SQL, since you have an unknown number of elements to insert.  **This is an exceptionally bad idea.**